# GCD Queue Incompatible Type Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

Alright, this is my first post and am still rather new at objective-c, but here it goes:

I am currently creating a project that will create a second queue to generate a bunch of NSTimers and set them off. Since I don't want to halt the main queue, I figured Grand Central Station was the best route.

Currently, I have a UIButton that performs the following action:

```
- (IBAction)runTest:(id)sender {
    if (!timerQueue) {        
        timerQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myApp.timerQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
}

dispatch_async(timerQueue, ^{[self initiateTest];});
```

and then...

```
- (void) initiateTest {

// code to generate timers and execute

}
```

The header file associated with the viewController where this all happens looks like this:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <SomeOtherMgrDelegate> {
    dispatch_block_t timerQueue;
}

...

- (IBAction)runTest:(id)sender;
- (void) initiateTest;
```

The issue seems to be with regards to the line

```
timerQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myApp.timerQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
```

Which generates a rather long-winded semantic issue that reads:

> Assigning to '__strong dispatch_block_t' (aka 'void (^__strong)(void)') from incompatible type 'dispatch_queue_t' (aka 'NSObject *')

Any idea why this error might be generating? It seemed in the documentation that this was the correct way to go about it.

Thanks; and let me know if there is anything else in my code that might be useful to see!

EDIT: So this was a rather dumb mistake, but for others: make sure the types match up (blocks /= queues!). The .h file associated with the viewController SHOULD look like this:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <SomeOtherMgrDelegate> {
    dispatch_queue_t timerQueue; // This is where the problem was.
 }

...

- (IBAction)runTest:(id)sender;
- (void) initiateTest;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared `timerQueue` as an instance of `dispatch_block_t`, when it should be `dispatch_queue_t`, the return type of `dispatch_queue_create()`

Comment: Thanks! I figured it was something dumb like that. Seems to be working fine now!

Answer (score 0):

Read the error. Look at the docs for the return value of `dispatch_queue_create`. And finally look at how you declared `timerQueue`. It's the wrong type.

You need:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <SomeOtherMgrDelegate> {
    dispatch_queue_t timerQueue;
}
```